# Jquery Dialog Dynamic Buttons Are Not Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add dynamic buttons in dialog box. I am using the following script without success. The button "Close" does not show up when I extend the dialog. What did I wrong ?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div>

<div id="dialog">
    Dialog bodyyyy
</div>


</div>
<script>
var mydialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
            dialogClass: "noclose",
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "Modal",
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto"
        });

var btns = mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons");

$.extend(btns, { "Close": function () { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); } });

mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons", btns);

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ujc7k9ww/4/

Comment: Seems to work for me too in chrome & IE.

Comment: I created brand new html file with the following script but again without success. The changes are in the post.

Comment: Is jQuery loading in your page? Any 404 errors?

Comment: No there are no errors.